# getBoundingClientRect is not returning correct value after resize

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have created a directive to append a dropdown to the body when it is shown. The calculation works perfectly inside `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle but whenever I am trying to use the same calculation inside `window.resize` event `getBoundingClientRect` does not return correct values.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appendDropdownToBody]'
})
export class AppendDropdownToBodyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
        private _el: ElementRef,
        private _renderer: Renderer2,
        private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //Works fine
        this.appendToBody();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event: Event) {
        //Not working properly
        this.appendToBody();
    }

    private appendToBody() {
        const dropdownEl = this._el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        const parentEl = dropdownEl.parentElement as HTMLElement;
        const parentElRect = parentEl.getBoundingClientRect() as DOMRect;
        this._renderer.appendChild(document.body, dropdownEl);

        this._renderer.setStyle(
            dropdownEl,
            'top',
            parentElRect.bottom + 10 + 'px'
        );
        this._renderer.setStyle(dropdownEl, 'left', parentElRect.left + 'px');
        this._renderer.setStyle(dropdownEl, 'width', parentElRect.width + 'px');
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the window have been resized ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this comes from a delay between the window resizing and the element resizing. For example, if there is another event listener that resizes the element after this listener triggers.

You can use a `ResizeObserver` to observe the element itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[resizeListener]',
})
export class ResizeListenerDirective {
  observer = new ResizeObserver(this.callback);

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.observer.observe(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  callback(entries: ResizeObserverEntry[], observer: ResizeObserver) {
    console.log(entries[0].target.getBoundingClientRect());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hjxxkk?file=src/app/resize-listener.directive.ts

Note: You may need to add `@types/resize-observer-browser` to get the typescript types.